# Can you express opinion about something external with "I feel like"?

Tags: expressions

Can you express opinion about something external with "I feel like"?

E.g. 1. *I feel like this solution won't resolve the problem*

Also, how about: 2. *I feel that this solution won't resolve the problem*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can.  It weakens the opinion since it suggests that you don't have any evidence for your view. Instead of basing your opinion on evidence, your opinion is based on your intuition, feelings and emotional judgement.

But grammatically both are fine, and both are reasonably idiomatic.  The form with "Like" is weaker.

Comment: I do feel this puts it at the opposite end of the personal interaction scale to "Your %$£# idea is the worst I've ever heard.";)

Comment: Question is not about constructing arguments but asking is this used. Recommended action is to remove comments about "like being weaker" and word use undermining the argument.

Comment: I feel that adding information about this nuance in meaning is useful to the OP and others reading the question and answer.  English Learners are often rightly concerned with the rhetorical impact of a statement, and this is an important aspect of English Learning.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feel-like), "feel like" means

> to have a wish for something, or to want to do something, at a particular moment

The sentence that you provided is not about wishing or wanting, so it's not correct to use "feel like".

Using "feel like" in this way presents a risk: the word "like" is a filler word that is used frequently by inarticulate people, and so it could be interpreted as

> I feel, like, this solution won't resolve the problem

In addition, the Cambridge Dictionary does not provide examples for "feel that": though, as this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feel%20that%2C%20think%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows, "feel that" is relatively common, though less so than "think that".

If you do say "feel like", people will understand what you mean, but will think less of your opinion, for three reasons:

- it's not a correct usage of "feel like"
- "feel" is weaker than "think"
- "like" is a word frequently used by inarticulate people.

Comment: Maybe it's a UK thing, but if I told a stubborn person 'I feel like I'm talking to a brick wall', I don't think anybody would take particular note. I will not comment on this quote from a US NBA baseball player: _I feel like I should thank the NBA for gifting me with a Christmas gift of playing on Christmas Day_

Comment: Let's not forget a UK advertising campaign that still provokes shudders among the sensitive. The product was a range of ready made sauces in jars intended to make preparing a chicken dish quick and easy. It was called 'Chicken Tonight', and it managed to get _three_ meanings out of that 'I feel like chicken tonight'. The ads featured a guy in the sauces aisle of a supermarket spotting a jar of this goop, making his arms like chicken wings, flapping them,  and hopping about, to the accompaniment of a song on the sound track: 'I feel like chicken tonight, chicken tonight, chicken tonight!'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "I feel like I'm talking to a brick wall" is using the verb  "feel" in its normal sense, rather than the phrasal verb meaning of "feel like". Your feeling is like that of talking to a brick wall.

Comment: In the US as well, the original sentence seems completely unremarkable and I can't really see anyone considering it incorrect.  I can't understand why you are calling it incorrect when you agree that MichaelHarvey's "I feel like I'm talking to a brick wall" is correct.  Even the Cambridge Dictionary's entry for [feel](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feel?q=feel+) includes "I feel like I've been cooped up in this flat for days."

Comment: @stangdon At the OP mentioned in their question, it's about whether you can use "I feel like" about something external. "I feel like **I'm**... " is describing what **I** feel. When I say  "I feel like **this solution**...", it isn't about what **I** feel, it's about my opinion of something external.

Comment: I feel like common usage suggests "i feel like" is a common construction in spoken English that is used ubiquitously by many English speakers. English learners may struggle to memorize all the official doctrines but benefit greatly by learning common usage.  Recommended action is to remove the remark about it being improper use then move this answer to some other question about strict linguistic rules that don't hold in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a very common construction in spoken English. Some regions may prefer using "think" instead of "feel like" in written communication.